# How to inject Authentication in mvcmock unit testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, authentication, mockmvc

**Overview**

I have a REST service with injected authentication and I want to create a unit test for it by using mockmvc. My RestController class is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.blss.security.securityCommon.entities.SecureOperatorDetails;
import com.blss.security.securityGateway.providers.AccAuthenticationProvider;

import lombok.Data;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gateway")
public class AuthenticationDetailsRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userdetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserDetailsResource currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {

        ArrayList<String> rolesList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        authorities
            .forEach(a -> {
                if (!a.getAuthority().startsWith(
                    AccAuthenticationProvider.CAD_TOKEN_AUTHORITY_PREFIX)) {
                    rolesList.add(a.getAuthority());
                }
            });

        SecureOperatorDetails operator = ((SecureOperatorDetails) authentication.getDetails());

        return new UserDetailsResource(
                authentication.getName(),
                operator.getOperator().getName(),
                operator.getOperator().getPermittedRetailerIds(),
                operator.getOperator().getStores(),
                operator.getOperator().getRetailerId(),
                operator.getDefaultStoreId(),
                operator.getDeviceId(),
                rolesList);
    }

    @Data
    static class UserDetailsResource {
        private final String username;
        private final String name;
        private final Set<String> retailerIds;
        private final Set<String> stores;
        private final String retailerId;
        private final String storeId;
        private final String deviceId;
        private final ArrayList<String> roles;
    }
}
```

**Issue**

I don't know how to mock authentication and inject it in my test class in order to avoid ***401 http exception*** or ***full authentication is required to access this resource***.

> Now I would be grateful if anyone can help me solve this problem

Comment: bypassing authentication? sounds fishy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added following code snippets to my test class and then the authentication was injected properly:

1. Add this to have a customized authentication:

   ```
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Autowired
   private Authentication authentication;   
   @Bean
   public Authentication authentication() {
       Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
       authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
       UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("customUsername", "customPassword", authorities); return authentication; }
   ```

   - Add following to setup method:

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                     .addFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter())
                     .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                     .apply(springSecurity())
                     .build(); 
     }

---

Notes:

- springSecurity() used in order to enable authentication injection; otherwise, the authentication object will be null in the main class (The class you wrote test for it).
- SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); is used in order to inject the customized authentication; otherwise, the default one will be injected by springSecurity()

Answer (score 1):

You may configure authentication mock using `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers`

Then you should init it as next :

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Override
protected void before() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(context).apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()).build();
}
```